# Calling library file - client side node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling the client library from node.js. I need to create an object of that library and for the same i have included the js in app.js and page.js where the head scripts are defined.

When i try to create an object of that library i get

```
ReferenceError: objLib is not defined
```

I need to know the way to include a library file in node.js

Comment: the standard way is `var mylib=require(PATH_TO_LIB)` , but it should compatible with require in order to be loaded correctly, and compatible with node, so it can run smoothly

Comment: it isn't specific to node. so that library doesn't have anything with module.exports or exports. That library uses window object

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Also, when i require the js file. I end up with "module not found" error. tried with absolute path, relative path.

Comment: well the module you are trying to load is not made for node.js , window object is not available in nodejs, you can fake it, but you will end up, with a lot of unnecessary code.. try by `require(./MODULENAME.js` , notice the `./` means in the same directory. it should not throw an `module not found` error

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I had tried this before too, and tried now as well. It gives same error.